Line-separated MatrixPlot based on magnitude
Given the matrix
mat = {{3, 9, 27, 81, 243}, {5, 21, 81, 297, 1053}, {9, 49, 225, 945, 3753}, {17, 113, 593, 2769, 12033}, {33, 257, 1505, 7681, 36033}, {65, 577, 3713, 20481, 102785}};
I would like to generate a MatrixPlot which will be divided in two regions according to the magnitude of each cell (>1000 in this case). The two regions should be separated by a red line as shown in the following Figure :

So far I've drawn up the line point by point :
MatrixPlot[mat, ColorFunction -> "GrayTones", Mesh -> True, 
FrameTicks -> {Table[{i + 1, i}, {i, 0, Length[mat] - 1}], None, None, Table[{i, i}, {i, 0, Length[mat[[1]]]}]}, 
Epilog -> {
Table[Text[Style[mat[[i, j]], Black, 10, FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman 10"], {j - 0.5, Length[mat] - i + 0.5}], {i, Length[mat]}, {j, Length[mat[[1]]]}], Red, 
Line[{{2, 0}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 3}, {4, 5}, {5, 5}}]
}]

Final goal is to have a condition over the magnitude in order to generate the plot automatically.

You can traverse through all cells and check their left and top-left neighbour. If the boundary is in between, you put a line there.
findBoundaryLines[mat_, t_] := Module[{m, n},
  {m, n} = Dimensions[mat];
  Flatten@Quiet@Table[{
      If[i > 1 && mat[[i - 1, j]] <= t < mat[[i, j]], 
       Line[{{j - 1, n - i + 2}, {j, n - i + 2}}], Nothing],
      If[j > 1 && mat[[i, j - 1]] <= t < mat[[i, j]], 
       Line[{{j - 1, n - i + 1}, {j - 1, n - i + 2}}], Nothing]}, 
   {i, 1, m}, {j, 1, n}]];

t = 1000;
Show[MatrixPlot[...], Graphics[{Red, Thick, findBoundaryLines[mat, t]}]]



I had been working on an approach based on ListContourPlot but it was going nowhere. This is very nice! (+1)
